# Windows 10 - easily switchable Radeon GPU drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, virtual-reality

I have a daft situation where one flight simulator I regularly play crashes unless I'm using the very latest GPU drivers, and a different flight simulator I regularly play crashes unless I'm using graphics card drivers from several versions ago. Crashes in the computational sense, though pilot ability might often contribute to the aviation sense.

The machine is utterly resiliant to any stress tests I throw at its CPU, GPU or RAM; or all of those things simultaneously; without suffering any failures or hitting what you could call a thermal ceiling. This does appear to be a daft situation where one set of drivers works for one thing, and another for t'other. I've used memtest86+, unigine benchmarks (one of which thrashes the VR), and fur benchmark (which can thrash all 12 virtual cores at the same time). All works faultlessly.

Is there a straightforward way to install two versions of the Radeon software (or the bare drivers) and switch between them dynamically?

FWIW, this is using a Valve Index VR headset, in both software's cases via an old version of Revive (because one of them doesn't support the latest version of that either). [goes slightly bald]

Comment: I don't know of any solution that doesn't involve either re-installing the driver anew each time, or having two video adapters (preferably not of the same manufacturer to avoid sharing drivers).

Comment: Do you know if it is the game-drive relationship that is causing the divorc... er, crash, or something to do with the other systems involved, such as the VR headset? What do event logs indicate?

Comment: @music2myear Condor 2, which needs the older drivers, throws a blue screen with the latest drivers for ntdll.dll with the last message being about rendering either a terrain tile or clouds. I haven't seen WarThunder's logs on these older drivers. Open Hardware Monitor records secondly datapoints right up to the event indicating nothing untoward temperature wise.